crypto2 throws status '404 Not Found'
I am getting the following error from the crypto2-package,
# load coins
coins <- crypto2::crypto_list(
  only_active   = FALSE,
  add_untracked = FALSE
)
#> Warning in open.connection(con, "rb"): cannot open URL
#> 'https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/map': HTTP status was '404
#> Not Found'
#> Error in open.connection(con, "rb"): cannot open the connection to 'https://web-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/map'

Created on 2024-06-04 with reprex v2.1.0
Until recently this has been working as expected. I have tried with and without a VPN connection - is this issue on API or client side?
I was expecting an object with cryptocurrencies.

Seems related to this issue that's already open with the package author: https://github.com/sstoeckl/crypto2/issues/20

There has been a major change in the Coinmarketcap API, and the base url in {crypto2} is now obsolete. The author is working on a fix it seems. See latest commit.
In the mean time you can use {cryptoQuotes} as an alternative, if you need cryptocurrency data. Below is a MWE,
# load library
library(cryptoQuotes)

Hourly Bitcoin (BTC)
# get hourly
# Bitcoin
tail(
  BTC <- get_quote(
    ticker   = "BTCUSDT",
    interval = "1h"
  )
)

Output
#>                        open    high     low   close    volume
#> 2024-06-11 03:00:00 69454.6 69566.5 68479.4 68741.4 17137.138
#> 2024-06-11 04:00:00 68741.4 68996.9 67881.9 68285.8 33301.328
#> 2024-06-11 05:00:00 68285.9 68515.4 68189.0 68472.3  9231.694
#> 2024-06-11 06:00:00 68472.2 68472.2 67606.2 68040.0 21653.075
#> 2024-06-11 07:00:00 68040.1 68080.3 67670.1 67930.4  9094.521
#> 2024-06-11 08:00:00 67930.3 68007.4 67814.4 67833.6  2145.541

Charting (Example)
# chart
chart(
  ticker   = BTC,
  main     = kline(),
  indicato = list(
    bollinger_bands()
  ),
  sub      = list(
    volume()
  )
)


Created on 2024-06-11 with reprex v2.1.0
